# R: writing tables using complete cases to exclude NA

Tags: r

I'm trying to use R to select and write only three columns from larger input data files, and output each of those columns as its own .txt file. There are necessarily quite a few blank cells and R is outputting my .txt files correctly, however the blanks are being output as NA, like so:

```
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
138.388
142.604
NA
NA
NA
172.566
```

as opposed to what I need, which is:

```
138.388
142.604
172.566
```

My current code looks like this:

```
indata <- read.delim("mydata.txt",header=T,sep="\t",stringsAsFactors=F)
# columns to print
outcols <- c("Column1.info","Column2.info","Column3.info")

## loop through columns to print
for(outcol in outcols){
    # form outfile name
    outfilename <- paste0(gsub(".info","",outcol),".txt")
    # write column of interest
    write.table(indata[,outcol,drop=F],file=outfilename,sep="\t",quote=F,col.names=F,row.names=F)
}
```

I'm using R precisely because it better handles blank cells than does MATLAB; but how can I use, e.g., complete.cases() (or something else) to write only relevant data?

Comment: Sounds like maybe you want `na.omit()`? See [this](http://www.statmethods.net/input/missingdata.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
na.omit() will remove the entire row.
```

if you want to remove only the NA elements from your col. Try this it might help. Considering df is your dataset of your three cols.

```
list <- apply(df,2,function(x) x[!is.na(x)])# Removing NA row wise
Len <- max(sapply(list,length)).#Creating a standard matrix by replacing blanks with NA in the end 
data <-sapply(list,function(x) c(x,rep(NA,len-length(x))))
```